# AngularJS 2: Pass component extra attributes to template

Tags: angular

I tried passing extra attributes by adding `@Input` inside Component class which works fine. But, I am unsure how to pass all attributes defined on component directive i.e. any new class, id

```
<my-directive disabled style="color: red;">{{my name}}</my-directive>
```

should be expanded to

```
<button class="my-button" disabled style="color: red">{{my name}}</button>
```

In this, class attribute is written inside template file of component & `disabled style="..."` will be passed to template.

```
// Component code

import { Component } from 'angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-directive',
 template: `
          <button class="my-button">It should be fetched from outside</button>
        `
});


export class MyDirective{    
    constructor(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your component class code?

Comment: @rinukkusu component code added..

Answer (score 0):

For `style` you can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html) to set arbitrary styles but that is not related to inputs.

You can only set all inputs one by one. There is no way to set several or all inputs at once.

You can create an input for all yourself and spread the passed value to the inputs like

```
@Input() input1;
@Input() input2;
@Input() input3;

@Input() 
set all(data) {
  this.input1 = data.input1 || this.input1;
  this.input2 = data.input2 || this.input2;
  this.input3 = data.input3 || this.input3;
}
```

Comment: And how will I use these inputs while using component directive?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe `<my-directive [all]="{input1: 'a', input2: 'b', input3: 'c'}"></my-direcitve>` or ``<my-directive [all]="allValues"></my-direcitve>` where `allValues` is `{input1: 'a', input2: 'b', input3: 'c'}`.

Comment: I thought about this but I want something so that developer using my-directive need not to know how to pass extra attributes...it should be as simple as adding html attribute.

Comment: These are your options. One alternative would be shared services but otherwise  that's what Angular2 offers.